# R : Function to pass variables in a dataframe into a vector not working

Tags: r, function, dataframe, vector

So I am very new to R and have been trying to cram some R knowledge into my brain for a project at my work.

I am still learning the basics and can't seem to figure out why my function will not run. I don't get an error, It just doesn't produce anything in the Global Environment, nor can I call any variable named in my script.

```
Make_vector <- function(var1, var2, name){


 name <- c(var1:var2)

}

Make_vector(Data$PN1, Data$PN2, vector1)
```

I am not sure if there is a concept here that I am missing. I've tried importing my data both as a dataframe and not.

I am trying to make it so that I can efficiently turn every variable in a list of vars into a vector that I can turn into a matrix or some similar idea I may have not reached yet.

Edit:
Example of what I need the function (or loop honestly) to do for a bunch of variables:

The variable as it is outputted from the data:

```
  > Data$PN1
    > v1
      [1] Strongly agree    Agree             Strongly agree    Strongly agree    Disagree          Strongly agree   
  [7] Agree             Agree             Strongly agree    Strongly agree    Strongly agree    Strongly agree   

> Data$PN2
  [1] Strongly agree    Disagree          Agree             Strongly agree    Disagree          Strongly agree   
  [7] Disagree          Disagree          Agree             Strongly agree    Strongly agree    Strongly agree
```

What I need to do:

```
> c(Data$PN1)
  [1] 1 2 1 1 3 1 2 2 1 1 1 1

> c(Data$PN2)
  [1] 1 3 2 1 3 1 3 3 2 1 1 1
```

I need to be able to do this across at least 80 different variables. They would follow a pattern of PN1 to PN20 or MD1 to MD45.

Hope this helps a bit more!

Sorry if this is a noob question. No one at my work uses R, so I get to be the one to figure it out!

Comment: Could you give an example with sample input and expected output please?

Comment: You may need `assign`

Comment: Sure! One moment!

Comment: Could you elaborate on your example please? Your function has 3 parameters which are `var1` , `var2` and `name`, however your example currently only has sample data for `var1`. `var21`, `name` and the expected output are missing. The example doesn't have to consist of the actual data you're working. A small example with made up data is fine.

Comment: I have made another edit. Hopefully it helps more! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Your function showed and the expected output are very different

Comment: Well that would definitely explain why I am not getting the outcome I need. I am struggling on how to iterate through all of the variables I would need to turn in to a vector. I was hoping for that with the ":".

Comment: What is happening here is that you have factor variables in your data frame and you want to convert them to numeric. `c()` happens to do this, but `as.numeric()` would be better, `c()` is not very readable as evidenced by the confusion around your question. So your question seems to be something like "How do I convert all the factor variables in my dataframe to numeric?"

Comment: More likely to need as.numeric(as.character(...))

Comment: Ah, so yes part of my goal is to get my factor vars in numeric form I also need to try and create many vectors over a range of variables. This would have to be my biggest challenge. I am struggling to find a way to either loop, or preferably, write a function that will allow me to input my variable range and convert each one into a vector as shown above.

Comment: Please do not write functions like this. The proper way is `yourresult <- yourfunction(yourinput)`. You should not deviate from that general approach (unless you are an advanced R programmer and can evaluate the risks and benefits of alternative approaches).